# The .App path is not recognised in desired capabilities in my Appium setup

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation

I have set up my desired capabilities on Appium. See below.

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone11",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "udid": "90E65B8C-BF64-46F4-B067-A50D52A320FB",
  "app": "/Users/davidmacdougall/Downloads/ios-uicatalog-master/UICatalog/build/Release-iphonesimulator/UICatalog.app"
}
```

I am running it on my macbook pro and have xcode etc.. all installed and on the latest releases. I get an error when I try to start a session it says.

```
[HTTP] No route found for /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 7 ms - 21
```

But the full  path to the application to be tested is located on the same machine where the server is running and pointed to the .app application extension.
I thought it could also be an URL issue but I didn't set one I just linked to the path location for the .app file I have no idea how to proceed, as I cant see an error and I know the path is correct.

How can I get it to see the file and if not can I change the file location or make a new folder to contain the file. Does that require set up changes?

Answer (score 1):

The .app file URL looks correct.
Sharing the full code with the desired capabilities and iOS driver initialisation would be really helpful to analyse the actual root-cause.

As per the error message shared: “**No route found for /wd/hub/session”**, it seems like Appium server is not setup correctly.

Usually, qa testing companies follows the below approach of passing the desired capabilities while automating the mobile application.

Please try passing the capabilities in the below format. *Hope it will help!*

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", “iPhone11”); 
caps.setCapability("app", "/Users/davidmacdougall/Downloads/ios-uicatalog-master/UICatalog/build/Release-iphonesimulator/UICatalog.app"); 
// Similarly, please pass the other capabilities as well: automationName, UDID, xcodeOrgId, xcodeSigningId*

Please also initialise the iOS Driver and pass the Appium URL along with the desired capibilities
 driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), caps);
```